# Magento2 custom admin controller always redirects to the admin index page

Tags: magento2, router, admin-controller

I've created custom extension in the admin panel under the menu of products. The problem is that I can't get the controller working. Code as fallows:

in etc/adminhtml/menu.xml:

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Backend:etc/menu.xsd">
    <menu>
        <add id="Vendor_Gift::Gift" title="Gifts" module="Vendor_Gift" parent="Magento_Catalog::inventory" action="gift/gift/" resource="Vendor_Gift::gift"/>
    </menu>
</config>
```

-etc/adminhtml/routes.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:App/etc/routes.xsd">
    <router id="admin">
        <route id="gift" frontName="gift">
            <module name="Vendor_Gift" />
        </route>
    </router>
</config>
```

-in Vendor/Gift/Controller/Adminhtml/Gift/Index.php

```
<?php
namespace   Vendor\Gift\Controller\Adminhtml\Gift;

class Index extends \Magento\Backend\App\Action
{
    public function execute()
    {
        die('dd');
    }
}
```

The generated link in the menu Gifts is:
  http://77.81.188.106/admin/gift/gift/index/key/bc29dbd2656f4c8c13599c4c63e1485afd9ffc3440fe4f9d9ceec8171b03d87a/

I just don't get where am I mistaken, is it in the menu link tab .. ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out it was a combined problem - it was my fault and a flaw in Magento 2 module registration flaw.

When I first created my module I messed up the folder name of the module, so instead of the module being in Vendor/Gift it was in Vendor/Gitf.

After running

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
```

without running the command

```
php bin/magento module:enable Vendor_Module
```

then the problem happened. Apparently, when u run the

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
```

it goes trough every folder in

```
app/code/<all_the_vendors_folders>/<all_the_vendors_modules>
```

and if it find a file registration.php which registers a module, it probably only  checks if the module name declared in etc/module.xml matches the one in the registration.php file. The result of that is that the module gets registered correctly but is placed in the wrong folder for which you have absolutely no information because **php bin/magento setup:upgrade** didn't give any errors and registered the module successfully. After that everything in my module code was correct, but since the module was in the folder "Gitf" instead of "Gift" nothing worked as expected, but also no errors were thrown it any point. So - for any new beginners, watch out I've spend like 3 hours looking for this... until I wrote here and a user confirmed my code is correct - then I was my fatal mistake, which was never announced to me by the system.

Answer (score 4):

1. Double check to make sure all your files, folders and namespace are  correct.
2. Did you include the following files:

   - /Gift/registration.php
   - /Gift/composer.json
   - /Gift/etc/module.xml

Using the instruction you provide, I have recreated your module and it work find see demo https://github.com/magepal/stackexchange/tree/develop/102629

Edit

After do some research this is what I found. Once you copy a module to correct installation folder (i.e /app/code) it will automatically install (after running ./bin/magento setup:upgrade) regardless of if the folder structure matches the module name. The only think it care about is that the name in 'registration.php' and 'etc/module.xml' matches and all the different xmls will get merge (i.e menu)

Comment: yes, except of composer.json but no where is it said that it is necessary. I can see that the module is added to app/etc/config.php withe the value of 1

Comment: Did you get any error from `./bin/magento setup:upgrade`?

Comment: nope, none, and it lists the module at the bottom with value 1. checked again... it is not working... i just dont understand. do i really need the composer.json file ?

Comment: What happen if you disable that module and install the one from github?

Comment: i am checking as we speak

Comment: it is working.... now i really don't get it

Comment: Yeah... I cant be more stupid than that... my main folder in Vendor is not called Gift but Gitf..... good one... only 3 hours that took... How did it registered the module though and didn't give any error ?

Comment: Maybe I should make a new question about that and close this one.. because there is actually nothing wrong with the module ?

Comment: How did you enable your module? Normally if you try to enable a module that dont exist eg `./bin/magento module:enable MagePal_Gift3` you will  give error 
`Unknown module(s): 'MagePal_Gift3'`

Comment: i think i just did setup:upgrade without module:enable and it got registered...  Is that possible ? i will try to reproduce it.. but still.. when namespace Vendor\Gitf is not found... shouldn't it give error ? ? I mean... the admin router should look in Vendor\Gift\Controller\Adminhtml\Gift for the Index.php action... and when not found... how can it not throw an error ?

Comment: thank you for the help anyway... I had given up on this... if you hadn't respond I probably would've found it tomorrow :) thank you!

Comment: This seem to be a issue in magento, I just rename the module to MagePal_Gift1 from MagePal_Gift (after it was enabled) and there was no errors on bin/magento setup:upgrade and end up with the same as you original had. Also there does not seem to be a way to uninstall this module `./bin/magento module:uninstall MagePal_Gift` will result in `MagePal_Gift is not an installed composer package` even after change the name back to 'Gift'

Comment: Yeah, I checked that as well. I will write to the support.

Comment: You could create a github issue @ https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues

Comment: Thank you for the help anyway... it was may bad that am was stupid :) :) Yeah, do that for sure. Awesome man, 10x again. That turned out to be a usefull question after all ^^

Comment: can u change your answer to just say it was an issue with the github link, a lot of people might not see that

Comment: No problem.. I'm about to open another issue too on how to uninstall a module that was no install using composer.

Comment: What do you mean by "issue with the github link"?

Comment: After do some research this is what I found. Once you copy a module to correct installation folder (i.e /app/code) it will automatically install (after running `./bin/magento setup:upgrade`) regardless of if the folder structure matches the module name. The only think it care about is that the name in  'registration.php' and 'etc/module.xml' matches and all the different xmls will get merge (i.e menu)

Comment: Yeah, that is exactly what the flow is. As I said, I only ran the setup:upgrade command and it registered the module, and the module was registered with the right name. Which lets say it is ok, but the BIG problem is that when it does not find the namespace for a class after that... it should give error then, or at least give the error 'fodler does not exist' on setup:upgrade ... one of those 2 things must happen - otherwise ... it is not good :)

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/36024/discussion-on-answer-by-r-s-magento2-custom-admin-controller-always-redirects-to).